# Is Singleton pattern well used in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I only know the `UIApplication` is designed as singleton pattern. 
But in real project, is singleton mode well used in Swift?

Comment: Its depends on the application's business. Normally we use dependency injection in swift

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal Thank you. Could you recommend me some examples about it, like a Github project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common phrase you hear in the developer caves is *"I know singletons are bad but..."*, There seems to almost be a consensus that singletons are **"bad"** but we see them used everywhere by **Apple** and **third-party developers**, both in their apps and shared frameworks.

So your probably asking why we use singletons. I'll let you in.

1. **Apple uses them!** As third-party developers we look to apple for "Best practices" and any pattern Apple uses is commonly adopted by the community as well
2. **Convenience**. Singletons allow you to access an object from anywhere

   ```
    class LoginController: UIViewController {
         let nameLabel = UILabel()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         nameLabel.text = ApiService.shared.user.name
        }

      private func handleLogoutButtonOnTap() {
           ApiService.shared.logout()
        }
    }
   ```

Using ApiService singleton to retrieve a User object and also logout. I agree this is very convenient.

So what's so bad about singletons?

1. They are a global mutable shared state, bugs appear when state changes unexpectedly, perhaps by a new developer joining the team
2. The relationship between singletons and the code that uses them is not clearly defined
3. Managing their lifecycle can be tricky. Singletons are alive through the entire duration of your app. So managing them can be hard. This also makes it hard to write tests for the code, since you can't easily start from a clean slate in each case.

In conclusion, there are mixed opinions about singletons, and I'm not saying don't ever use them, but there are other options out there.

The community is moving away from using singletons, and leaning towards `Dependency Injection` instead. Read up about it

Comment: Thank your all :D